# Symfony : distribution bundles

Tags: symfony

I have a site for sport association. 
This association offers courses, traineeships and parties.
So there is the participants to the courses, to the traineeships and to the parties.
There is also the teachers (participate to courses, traineeships and parties).

I want to divide my app into these bundles :

- UserBundle (teachers and the differents participants)
- CoursesBundle
- TraineeshipsBundle
- PartiesBundle
- SeasonBundle (All informations about a season (ex : 2015/2016))
- UserActivitiesBundle (association between Users, these 3 differents activities and Season)

**But CoursesBundle, TraineeshipsBundle and PartiesBundle use necessary UserBundle and SeasonBundle (so there is a small dependance).**

What do you think about my bundles ? What is the technics for a optimal dividing ?

Comment: On a first thought, I would say you're overcomplicating... This seems like a lot of bundles for a one single app, but I might be wrong...

Comment: If you have not already done so then take a look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html.  The 'official' recommendation is to avoid multiple bundles unless you really plan on reusing a given bundle in multiple applications.  I am not so sure about that approach.  I tend to break things up by bundles even within a given app just to make the code a bit more organized.  You might start with just one bundle then refactor if the code base becomes difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thank you but I can't start with just one bundle (I have a constraint haha), but thank you, I will see this link